# Google App Engine: new java.util.Date() how reliable?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have a servlet in google app engine like this:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        resp.getWriter().println("Date:"+new Date());
}
```

This works and I have tested it. 
It returns: Date:

> Tue Dec 13 21:22:24 UTC 2011

when it was pretty much that time.

My question is how reliable is it going to be ? 
Does the google app engine guarantees the time on its machines to a certain extent.

I would like to modify this servlet to return certain different values depending on the day the user will visit the site (note: day not hour).
My idea is that the servlet would return this value as a json then used by the main html page. The question then is it possible for GAE then to completely give me a bad date (like 2 days ago) and completely screw my logic.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

App Engine servers are NTP synced, like every other production machine on earth. There's no firm guarantee on the maximum drift, but it will be small.

Comment: so I can not rely on it ? it'd be small 99% of the time but then it can be suddenly wrong...

Comment: @Xnzo72 You can rely on it as much as you can rely on time sync on any other production machine: practically speaking, it will be within a small margin of the 'correct' time, but it's impossible to guarantee. This is the best you can get _anywhere_.

Comment: Where in the google app engine documentation can I find out about this ? I need to rely on it just in terms of days (not seconds, not minutes) so that would be good. But I need to be 100% sure that I can do it. i can not have the date to be a week in the past.

Comment: @Xnzo72 It's not specific to App Engine - or Google. Just don't worry about it - NTP sync means you're unlikely to ever have this as a problem.